# why doesn't modelform_factory use my model field attributes

Tags: django-models, django-forms

I have the following model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myField = models.CharField()
    myOtherField = models.CharField()

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):            
        super(MyModel,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._meta.get_field_by_name("myField")[0].default = get_default_value()
        self._meta.get_field_by_name("myOtherField")[0]._choices = get_choices()

def get_default_value():
    # obviously, this does more than just return a static value; 
    # how I actually get the default value for this field isn't relevant for this question
    return "my default value"

def get_choices():
    # as above, how this works is irrelevant
    return [("one","one"),("two","two")]

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel


MyFormFactory = modelform_factory(MyModel)

def MyView(request):
    model = MyModel()
    form1 = MyForm(instance=model)
    form2 = MyFormFactory(instance=model)
    return render_to_response('my_template.html',{'form1':form1, 'form2':form2})
```

form1 gets rendered properly, with the default value for myField and myOtherField rendered as a Select with appropriate choices.  But form2 just has two blank TextInput fields.  Any idea how to ensure that the form generated from the modelform_factory method respects those attributes?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to see a series of edit forms for each object, I believe you need to set the queryset parameter when using the generated factory. The default behavior is to show all objects, plus an empty form.

```
def MyView(request):
    ...
    form2 = MyFormFactory(instance=model, queryset=MyModel.objects.all())
```

This [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function) may help.

Take this with a grain of salt. This is my first day playing around with Python.